# Is there a way to transfer money and items from iOS to Android?

Tags: ios, android, jetpack-joyride

I've been playing Jetpack Joyride on iOS, and I just got an Android device. Can I move my things, such as money and unlocks, from my iOS device to Android?

Comment: May I please add Windows 8 to that equation?

Answer (score 4):

In the most recent update, they added a feature called the **Halfbrick Profile**.

Get one, login with the profile, and all your items will be transfered.

Answer (score 2):

No. I am sorry that I don't have better info than just no. However all of the things I can think of, that are preventing you from doing this, are incredibly difficult to put into words.

Chiefly, incompatible operating systems, no user log in, the developer has not made this possible.

If you were handy with coding and über leet hax, then a work around might be available. But that would be tricky and potentially dangerous for your device.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a tool called [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) to get at the game files on your iOS device. After that, you should be able to transfer those files to any other device.

Thats only way I know of to transfer the files across.